# Download workitem attachments from TFS (files corrupted)

Tags: c#, tfs

I am trying to create C# code, so I can automatically download all attachments for predefined query of BUGS from Team Foundation Server. The code seems to work just fine, yet all downloaded files are for an unexpected reason corrupted and I cannot view them. Could someone please take a look at the code and share an opinion? Many thanks for the help!

```
static void Main()
        {
            // Connection to the Team Project Collection
            TfsTeamProjectCollection tpc = TfsTeamProjectCollectionFactory.GetTeamProjectCollection(
              new Uri("https://xxx.visualstudio.com/defaultcollection"));

            // Get a WorkItemStore object for the Team Project Collection.
            WorkItemStore workItemStore = new WorkItemStore(tpc);

            // Run a query.
            WorkItemCollection queryResults = workItemStore.Query(
              @"SELECT *
    FROM WorkItems
    WHERE [System.WorkItemType] = 'Bug'
    AND [Language] = 'xxx'
    AND [How Found] = 'xxx'
    AND [Assigned to] = 'xxx'
    ORDER BY [Changed Date] DESC");

            // Get a WebClient object to do the attachment download
            WebClient webClient = new WebClient()
            {
                UseDefaultCredentials = true
            };

            // Loop through each work item.
            foreach (WorkItem workItem in queryResults)
            {
                // Loop through each attachment in the work item.
                foreach (Attachment attachment in workItem.Attachments)
                {
                    // Construct a filename for the attachment
                    string filename = string.Format("C:\\TEST\\{0}_{1}", workItem.Fields["ID"].Value, attachment.Name);
                    // Download the attachment.
                    webClient.DownloadFile(attachment.Uri, filename);
                }
            }
```

Comment: Did this error only occurs  on your dev machine? Could you give a try on another machine?

Comment: Hi. Yes the error is exactly same on my colleagues machines as well. I am wondering whether this could be an authentication problem. When normally login into the VSTS I need to use a phone authentication + credentials. Yet it is strange as the code is able to get all attachment, but in a corrupted form. I have also found the following article, where code uses token auth. but it's for the opposite process (attachment upload / not download). Many thanks for help.

Comment: Give a try with the method in this blog http://www.timschaeps.com/team-foundation-service-downloading-attachments-from-work-items-through-the-api/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is caused by the WebClient didn't authenticate to TFS server correctly. Instead of using WebClient to download the file, you can use `WorkItemServer.DownloadFile()` method in `Microsoft.TeamFoundation.WorkItemTracking.Proxy` to download the file. Refer to the code below for details:

```
foreach (Attachment atm in workItem.Attachments)
            {
                WorkItemServer wise = tpc.GetService<WorkItemServer>();
                string file = wise.DownloadFile(atm.Id);
                File.Copy(file,"C:\\TEST\\" + atm.Name,true);

            }
```

Answer (score 0):

For the authentication, you can add below code to authenticate the project collection level.

```
//get credentials by logging in with a user interface
var credentialsProvider = new UICredentialsProvider();

var teamProjectCollection = new TfsTeamProjectCollection(collection, credentialsProvider);
teamProjectCollection.Authenticate();
```

More details please refer this blog: [Team Foundation Service: Downloading attachments from work items through the api](http://www.timschaeps.com/team-foundation-service-downloading-attachments-from-work-items-through-the-api/)

Comment: Hi Patrick. Thanks a lot for the code and link. I've tried this one and the result is the same. All attachments are corrupted and thus unreadable. I know, TFS could also generate "Personal access tokens" for third party applications to access. Yet, as I am not an expert in this, do you have any idea, how could this be possible to implement within my code? I am almost certain, that the problem has to do something with invalid access to TFS. I've tried to edit the code so it exports all attachments.Uri and each link is perfectly accessible through the browser. Thanks a lot for your help!

Comment: If you wish to provide the personal access token through an HTTP header, you must first convert it to a Base64 string (the following example shows how to convert to Base64 using C#).  More details please refer this link: https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/docs/integrate/get-started/auth/overview

Answer (score 0):

The file is not corrupted, The downloaded attachments are coming in zip format. You can check the size of the "Corrupted file".It will be less in size. So while downloading you put the file name as =====> filename+".zip" ===>this will give us proper file when you extract and look at it.

Example.

1. Dummy.docx ==> file in source ===> 290kb
2. Dummy.docx ==> file in
   destination ===> 280kb ==> cannot open this file

Solution.

3. Dummy.docx.zip ===> extract file will give Dummy.docx (290 kb)==> can open this and view the data.