# How to programmatically download attachments in Azure DevOps?

Tags: c#, azure-devops

I'm trying to programmatically download 90+ attachments from a user story in VSTS using TeamFoundation/VisualStudio C# API that I downloaded from Nuget.   I was trying to use this example: https://intellitect.com/downloading-attachments-from-tfs/

However, that code seems to be out of date.  I cannot seem to find these exact packages mentioned in article: nuget-bot.Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Client
nuget-bot.Microsoft.TeamFoundation.WorkItemTracking.Client

However, I downloaded TFS packages that are there such as Microsoft.TeamFoundationServer.Client and Microsoft.TeamFoundationServer.ExtendedClient but the WorkItem class does not seem to have an Attachments no more.  Does somebody know where I can find the Attachments property?   I browsed the Object Browser in Visual Studio and cannot find it.  Or can you suggest an alternate solution to get attachments from a work item?  Thanks.

Comment: I don't know the solution if the `Attachments` property is gone, but one workaround would be to call the API directly using a REST client. [Get the work item](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/vsts/wit/work%20items/get%20work%20item) and then [get the attachments](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/vsts/wit/attachments/get).

Comment: Thanks Dan.  I've looked into this before but I don't see how I can retrieve the attachment id.  The WorkItem properties only give you things like work item title, etc.  I want to be able to loop through all the attachments in the work item and download them.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> **WebClient** cannot authenticate to VSTS correctly. Instead of using WebClient to download the file, you can use
>   `WorkItemServer.DownloadFile()`method in
>   `Microsoft.TeamFoundation.WorkItemTracking.Proxy` to download the
>   file. See [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40984056/download-workitem-attachments-from-tfs-files-corrupted) for details.

You can use below sample to download the attachment for a specific work item:

Note: Install the the nuget package [Microsoft.TeamFoundationServer.ExtendedClient](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.TeamFoundationServer.ExtendedClient/)

```
using Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Client;
using Microsoft.TeamFoundation.WorkItemTracking.Client;
using Microsoft.TeamFoundation.WorkItemTracking.Proxy;
using System;
using System.IO;

namespace VSTS_DownloadWITAttachment
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            TfsTeamProjectCollection ttpc = new TfsTeamProjectCollection(new Uri("https://account.visualstudio.com/"));
            ttpc.EnsureAuthenticated();
            WorkItemStore wistore = ttpc.GetService<WorkItemStore>();
            WorkItem wi = wistore.GetWorkItem(94);
            WorkItemServer wiserver = ttpc.GetService<WorkItemServer>();
            string tmppath = wiserver.DownloadFile(wi.Attachments[0].Id); //Change the number to download other attachments if there are more then one attachments for the specific work item. e.g: [1] to download the second one.
            string filename = string.Format("D:\\WITAttachments\\{0}-{1}", wi.Fields["ID"].Value, wi.Attachments[0].Name);
            File.Copy(tmppath, filename);
        }
    }
}
```

Then you can try to query the work items and download the attachments in a loop for each of them. See [Fetch work items with queries programatically in VSTS](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/vsts/integrate/quickstarts/work-item-quickstart?view=vsts#c-code-snippet) for details.

Below sample for your reference:

```
using Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Client;
using Microsoft.TeamFoundation.WorkItemTracking.Client;
using Microsoft.TeamFoundation.WorkItemTracking.Proxy;
using Microsoft.TeamFoundation.WorkItemTracking.WebApi;
using Microsoft.TeamFoundation.WorkItemTracking.WebApi.Models;
using Microsoft.VisualStudio.Services.Common;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.IO;
using System.Linq;
using System.Net;

namespace DownloadWITAttachments
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Uri uri = new Uri("https://account.visualstudio.com");
            string PAT = "xxxxxxxxxxxx";
            string project = "ProjectName";

            VssBasicCredential credentials = new VssBasicCredential("", PAT);

            //create a wiql object and build our query
            Wiql wiql = new Wiql()
            {
                Query = "Select * " +
                        "From WorkItems " +
                        "Where [Work Item Type] = 'User Story' " +
                        "And [System.TeamProject] = '" + project + "' " +
                        "And [System.State] <> 'Closed' " +
                        "And [System.AttachedFileCount] > 0 " +
                        "Order By [State] Asc, [Changed Date] Desc"
            };

            //create instance of work item tracking http client
            using (WorkItemTrackingHttpClient workItemTrackingHttpClient = new WorkItemTrackingHttpClient(uri, credentials))
            {
                //execute the query to get the list of work items in the results
                WorkItemQueryResult workItemQueryResult = workItemTrackingHttpClient.QueryByWiqlAsync(wiql).Result;

                if (workItemQueryResult.WorkItems.Count() != 0)
                {
                    //Download the first attachment for each work item.
                    foreach (var item in workItemQueryResult.WorkItems)
                    {
                        TfsTeamProjectCollection ttpc = new TfsTeamProjectCollection(uri);
                        ttpc.EnsureAuthenticated();
                        WorkItemStore wistore = ttpc.GetService<WorkItemStore>();
                        Microsoft.TeamFoundation.WorkItemTracking.Client.WorkItem wi = wistore.GetWorkItem(item.Id);
                        WorkItemServer wiserver = ttpc.GetService<WorkItemServer>();                       
                        string tmppath = wiserver.DownloadFile(wi.Attachments[0].Id);
                        string filename = string.Format("D:\\temp\\vsts\\{0}-{1}", wi.Fields["ID"].Value, wi.Attachments[0].Name);
                        File.Copy(tmppath, filename);
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks Andy, but I do have that Nuget package installed and do not see these below.   I have the latest version: 15.132.0-preview.   What version are you using?          Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Client;
using Microsoft.TeamFoundation.WorkItemTracking.Client;
using Microsoft.TeamFoundation.WorkItemTracking.Proxy;

Comment: @ray500 I installed the `-Version 15.112.1`, you can have a try for that:https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.TeamFoundationServer.ExtendedClient/

Comment: Thanks Andy.  I see it there but I hope Microsoft won't remove them.  The prerelease I mentioned don't have them.  The solution works!!

Answer (score 4):

If you don't already have an access token for interacting with the API, generate one.

Make an API call to get the expanded work item information. Note the `$expand=all` parameter to retrieve all item details.

```
GET https://{account}.visualstudio.com/{project}/_apis/wit/workitems/115258?api-version=4.1&$expand=all
```

The response should look something like this (if the item has attachments).

```json
{
    "id": 115258,
    "rev": 4,
    "fields": {
        "System.Id": 115258,
        "System.AreaId": 2643
        ...and so on...
    },
    "relations": [
        {
            "rel": "AttachedFile",
            "url": "https://{account}.visualstudio.com/d6c4b828-0f7e-4b69-a356-a92c0ec3cd07/_apis/wit/attachments/5682f031-4b09-478c-8042-0d2a998905e4",
            "attributes": {
                "authorizedDate": "2018-04-30T19:34:09.763Z",
                "id": 2015371,
                "resourceCreatedDate": "2018-04-30T19:34:07.873Z",
                "resourceModifiedDate": "2018-04-30T19:32:16.057Z",
                "revisedDate": "9999-01-01T00:00:00Z",
                "resourceSize": 47104,
                "name": "file.jpg"
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

Iterate over the `relations` where the `rel` is `AttachedFile` and call the `url` to get the attachment content.

```
GET https://{account}.visualstudio.com/d6c4b828-0f7e-4b69-a356-a92c0ec3cd07/_apis/wit/attachments/5682f031-4b09-478c-8042-0d2a998905e4
```

Sources:

- [Work Items - Get Work Item](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/vsts/wit/work%20items/get%20work%20item)
- [Attachments - Get](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/vsts/wit/attachments/get)

Comment: Thanks Dan.  I found this and tried it in Visual Studio but I could not get the HTTPResponse to give me the file with the data.  So I tried Andy's solution and it worked.

Comment: Why the POST? Get Attachments is documented as a GET.

Comment: You're correct @Matthieu, it should be `GET`. Updated.